# Computed Property not updating after direct set

Tags: ember.js

I think i am facing a bug regarding setting value directly to a computed property that seem to break computing when it's related keys changes again, here an example:

```
o = Ember.Object.extend({
    v1: null,
    v2: function (){
        console.log('evaluation of v2', arguments);
        return this.get('v1') + '!!!';
    }.property('v1'),
    v1_Observer: function () {
        console.warn('v1 changed:', this.get('v1'));
    }.observes('v1'),
    v2_Observer: function (){
        console.info('v2 changed:', this.get('v2'));
    }.observes('v2')
});

oi = o.create();
oi.set('v1', 'Value v1 one');
oi.set('v2', 'Value direct to v2');
oi.set('v1', 'Value v1 two');
Ember.assert('v2 should be "Value v1 two!!!"', oi.get('v2') === (oi.get('v1') + '!!!'));
```

I thinks there is 2 bugs here:

1. Everything works well until I update the computed property v2 directly with "set", when I update v1 again, v2 is not reevaluated.
2. when setting v2 directly its observer is called twice !

according to the documentation http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/ we can directly set the value of a computed property with 'set' witch will be called with 2 parameters (key, value)! but in my tests, the property v2 only fires once, when v1 changed the first time.

this is the output of the console :

```
evaluation of v2 ["v2"]
v2 changed: Value v1 one!!!
v1 changed: Value v1 one
v2 changed: Value direct
v2 changed: Value direct
v1 changed: Value v1 two
Assertion failed: v2 should be "Value v1 two!!!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember uses a `runloop` to optimize bindings and keep DOM updates to a minumum. It does this by putting property changes like these on a queue. The queue however is a little smarter.

If you were to say modify a property 10 times before it is rendered to the DOM, it will only use the last value you set for the property. As a result when you need to display the property in the DOM, it only needs to be updated once.

Further a computed property is a function that acts as both a getter and a setter depending on the number of arguments passed in. The syntax is,

```
myProperty: function(key, value) {
  if (value) {
    // setter
  } else {
    // getter
  }
}.property()
```

In the example above you are only returning the value computed from the dependent `v1`. You also need to provide a setter that puts backs the value into `v1` from the `v2` computed property.

Answer (score 1):

Running your examples, I see the following in my console

```
> oi = o.create();

> oi.set('v1', 'Value v1 one');
[Log] evaluation of v2 ["v2"]
[Log] v2 changed: Value v1 one!!!
[Warning] v1 changed: Value v1 one

> oi.set('v2', 'Value direct to v2');
[Log] v2 changed: Value direct to v2

> oi.set('v1', 'Value v1 two');
[Log] v2 changed: Value direct to v2
[Warning] v1 changed: Value v1 two
```

> List item when setting v2 directly its observer is called twice !

As you could've noticed, the observer of 'v2' is called twice in the row because you first set the value of `v1`, which makes `v2` recompute and the observer fire, and it runs the second time when you set `v2` directly — so there is nothing to wonder about.

> List item Everything works well until I update the computed property v2 directly with "set", when I update v1 again, v2 is not reevaluated.

Once you set `v2` manually, you basically tell computed property to go away and replace it with just a value (essentially, `v2` was a function and you set it to a value). Why would it re-eval?

Comment: thanks for answering ... if you notice, "v2" observer is called three times, one when setting "v1", twice when setting "v2" dirrectly, and this is what i don't expect, from the code, if I understood well "v2" observer should called 3 times: one when i set "v1", one when i set "v2" and 1 when I set "v1" again, and its final value should be "Value v1 two!!!"

Comment: My understanding is that actually it should've been called two times and the final value should be "Value direct to v2". The third time it's called might be a bug, but the final value is what it should be.

Comment: in my understanding, setting v1 should always make v2 to r-eval, even if I modified v2 directly before !
If what you say is true! manually changing v2 should always pass by setting v1, and instead we should use observers to change some values rather than computed !

Comment: my case raised with property isValid witch evaluate to validate input, but some times I need to force isValid, but when the input changes again isValid sould re-eval! if ember is not designed for that maybe include this in the doc could be necessaray.

Comment: When you manually set `v2`, it's no longer a computed property and it **is** the correct behavior. If you want to force some property, you could set some other property (say `forceValid`) and check for it in `isValid` to do what you want.

Comment: ok now I undestand it, thank you so much, but the doc should mention that manually set computed property will stop its computing.